# Self-Referencing entity inserts two records

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a "Category" entity which references self.

```
@Entity
public class Category extends NamedEntity {

    private String slug;

    private int position;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<Category>();

    ... getters / setters ...
```

When I save the entity which has no parent, it inserts "two" records:

| ID | NAME | POSITION | SLUG | PARENT_ID |

| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

| 2 | null | 0 | null | null |

I wanted to insert "one" record whose PARENT_ID is null, but it inserts the record(id=2) and the record(id=1) as a child.

I save the record using Spring-Data JPA interface API:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends Repository<Category, Long> {
    public Category findById(Long id) throws DataAccessException;
    public Category save(Category category) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping for `parent` to the following and it won't.

```
@ManyToOne
private Category parent;
```

The reason you observe this behavior is that the `CascadeType.PERSIST` will create a new empty category for you rather than Hibernate just creating the child record with a null'd parent.

Comment: When I removed cascade option, ```TransientPropertyValueException``` exception occurs. That's why I put ```CascadeType.PERSIST```.

Exception description is ```object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing```.

Thank you.

Comment: It should not complain if you set the value to `null` explicitly.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I have to say it results in the same.

Comment: quite strange.

I made ```populate``` method in ```Category``` class for the convinience. I just passed form data instance. I thought the fiels are explicitly set by calling this method.

However, it doesn't. It has to be TOTALLY EXPLICITLY set. ```category.setParent(null);``` It works, but I'm still confused why. Anyway, Thank you.